# memcpy in a different function having a pointer to pointer argument

Tags: c, pointers

I have a following function `process` calling a routine `dataFileBuffer` which takes a pointer to a pointer and does a memcpy on the dereferenced pointer location.

```
int dataFileBuffer(uint8_t *index, char **tempBuf,int size)
{   
   if(index != stop_address)) /*stop_address is a fixed pointer to the end buffer*/
   {
      if(*tempBuf)
      {
        if(index + size < stop_address)
            memcpy(*tempBuf,index,size);
        else
        {
            size  = stop_address-index-1;               
            memcpy(*tempBuf,index,size);    
        }
      }
      else
        size = 0;
  }
  else  
    size = 0;   
  return size;
}

int process()
{
    char *readBuf=NULL;    
    char *tBuf = (char *)malloc(MAX_LENGTH); 
    int readBytes = -1;
    uint8_t *index = start_address;
    uint8_t *complete = stop_address;
    do 
    {

       readBuf = tBuf+(sizeof(char)*40);
       readBytes = 0;
       readBytes = dataFileBuffer(index,&readBuf,MAX_LENGTH);
       if(readBytes > 0)
       {
           index = index+readBytes;
       }

   }while(index <= complete);
   return readBytes;
}
```

My `process` function is intermittently seeing stack corruptions which is making me think that something is wrong with my implementation of copy.

I just wanted to understand if we can pass a pointer to a pointer as an argument and safely memcpy to the dereferenced location in the called function ?

Comment: Are you coding c or c++?

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in c.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint at the `malloc` line in question, was the contents of the pointer in the correct area?  You would have to use a debugger to get this information.

Comment: Why are you taking a `char**` ? You don't modify the pointer for the caller, so just pass it `char*`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, it's mandated by the standard.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yea I am using gdb to debug the problem. but my question was it should be safe to memcpy the dereferenced pointer to a pointer in the called routine right ?

Comment: @Sean Historically they were changing the address of the pointer in the routine, not any longer, thought a change of definition might not be needed

Comment: For the sanity of people reading this, pls do not call `index` an integer variable that holds an address T_T

Comment: What is the return type of the function?  Just noticed that you didn't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the question's code. Apart from some syntax errors, there is notably the function

```
dataFileBuffer(index, char **tempBuf,int size)
```

which does not compile for two reasons, there is no type declared for the argument `index`, and there is no return value declared - note that the function ends with

```
return size;
```

and is called like this:

```
readBytes = dataFileBuffer(index,&readBuf,MAX_LEN);
```

and my guess is that it should be

```
int dataFileBuffer(char *index, char **tempBuf, int size)
```

but I am puzzled why you have reversed the arguments given to `dataFileBuffer()` for the `memcpy()`.

Next, you have used `MAX_LEN`, `MAX_LENGTH` and `40` to define buffers sizes or offsets, but there is no clear definition or checking as to the size of the available buffer `index` that you copy into - or is that *from* :-). It is more usual to offer a buffer size than a pointer limit.

You also have

```
...
readBytes = dataFileBuffer(index,&readBuf,MAX_LEN);
if(readBytes > 0)
    {
        index = index+readBytes;
    }
} while(index <= complete);
```

which is likely to cause an infinite loop when `readBytes == 0`, and anyway will copy the *same data* on subsequent loops.

Sorry I can't offer a proper solution, as it's all a confused mess.

**Added after OP comment**

In reply to the specific question about deferencing a `**pointer`, this example succeeds in doing that, by finding the string length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// return the length of the string
size_t slen(char **tempBuf)
{   
    return strlen (*tempBuf);
}

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "abcde";
    char *sptr = string;
    printf ("Length of '%s' is %d\n", string, slen (&sptr));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Length of 'abcde' is 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am sorry for my pseudo code kind of copy paste code, I just wanted to add the part of code which was relevant to the question with some visibility to the kind of code I am talking about. The actual code function is way more than this. I have added some edits to the code.
I guess I should have been more specific in asking the question which is: 
Is it okay to dereference a pointer to a pointer in the called function and use memcpy on it ?

Comment: @cmidi you should have posted a **minimal compilable example** that demonstrates the fault. If you post code that is "something like" your code, you just waste the time of commenters finding faults that do no exist in the "proper" program. There is a fault, so please do not post false faults.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @cmidi I have improved my post in answer to your specific question - testing the `**` dereference.